# How can i secure my api endpoint when there is no users registration

Tags: node.js, security, jwt

I have front end page - contact us - where every user can fill up the form and contact us.After that the filled form is send to our email. Because on our web site, there will not be user registration, so possible client can contact us but he will not need to sign up to visit our web site because it is not "friendly".

I always secured my web api with json web token, so i see if the user is registered in our db so he can have access to some api routes or not. But because this time there will be no DB with users, how can i secure my api endpoints ?

For example: malicious user comes to my website, he can see in the network tab the post request that is made for sending the email.
He can go in postman, and he can make thousands of request if he wants to my api endpoint and it will make me a problems because he is not filling the form on the frontend page, but maybe he will ping my endpoint very often with pre-made body post maked object in postman.

How can i prevent this things without user authentication ?

Answer (score -1):

So the only way that i found until now is to check the origin - from where the request is coming. We can write a middleware at the beggining of our .js file before all other routes and check that

```
const express = require('express');
const router = express.Router();
const helpers = require('../utils/helpers');
router.use(helpers.checkOrigin);

router.post("/sendemail", async (req, res) => {
   ...
})
```

**helpers.js file**

```
const checkOrigin = (req, res, next) => {
  console.log("checkOrigin", req.headers.origin);
  if(req.headers.origin == "www.yourdomain.com") {
    next();
  } else {
    res.status(403).json({error: "Unauthorized"});
  }
}
```

in the

```
console.log("checkOrigin", req.headers.origin);
```

when we send request from postman then it prints undefined so it goes to the else block
but if the request comes from [www.yourdomain.com](http://www.yourdomain.com) then it will go in the if block, execute next middleware and accept request from all routes below including - sendemail.

If anyone has other solutions and better please let me know !